# Combinatorics: Trying to figure algorithm (about subsets)

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, subset

I'm trying to solve a problem on TopCoder. Basically what I need is algorithms for the following:

Let S = [1, 2, ..., n] be a sequence. Let m be less than n.

1) Find all subsequences of S of size m (which is easy - n^m).

2) Find all subsequences of S of size m where the elements are in nondecreasing order.

3) Find all subsequences of S of size m where the elements are not allowed to be repeated (which is also easy - (n!)/((n-m)!).

4) Find all subsequences of S of size m where the elements are in nondecreasing order and are not allowed to be repeated.

Still trying to find formula for parts 2 and 4. A little bit of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Original problem:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1X1VK8Vq2DlqMbZpXHGLoWv9ULfRLVoLtMTRRU5nh5qs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm confused about the use of the term "set" here.  Sets tend to be unordered and to contain individual elements at most once, so I don't understand what question 2, 3 and 4 even mean.

Comment: hmmm, my fault
"set" in this problem is considered by the following properties:
1) [1, 2, 3] and [2, 1, 3] are different "sets"
2) [1, 1, 1] is a "set".
bonus for the proper name of "set" :)

Comment: if you get 2) you get 4) by the intersection of 2) and 3)

Comment: Oh.  Those are probably just `sequences`, in that case.

Comment: Your example suggest that `S` contains all the integers from `1..n` for some `n`.  Is that intentional or accidental ?

Comment: @TonyMorris so how to get 2?

Comment: @Gian thanks, helpful for my future questions :)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark intentional. if you are interested in actual problem, here it is: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1X1VK8Vq2DlqMbZpXHGLoWv9ULfRLVoLtMTRRU5nh5qs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

to solve 4), note that w/o repetitions 'non-decreasing' means 'increasing'. partition the set of all sequences of length `m` built from `S` without repeating elements into equivalence classes defined by the set of elements occurring in the subsequence. within each equivalence class, there is exactly one increasing sequence (elements ordered by `<`). the size of each equivalence class is the number of permutations of the elements. the number of 4)-sequences therefore is `(n!)/((n-m)! * m!) = n \choose m`.

ad 2), model the sequence as a sequence of occurrence counts (including 0 for non-inclusion) for all elements in `S`. this can be written as a sequence of pairs `(s_i, k_i), i=1..n; s_i \in S, k_i \in IN, \foreach p,q in {1..n}, p!=q: s_p != s_q` of length exactly `n`. 'non-decreasing' implies a unique permissible ordering of the sequence given by arranging the elements according to increasing `s_i`. thus the only degree of freedom is the occurrence count which must obey the constraint of summing to m: `sum_{i=1..n} k_i = m`.

this problem is equivalent to partitions with (particular) restrictions and counting lattice paths. i don't think there is a closed formula for the number of n-tuples from `IN^n` meeting this condition.

however, there is a standard algorithm to enumerate all possibilities, eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)